# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on vagrant up

Tags: 16.04, vagrant

Every time I run `vagrant up`, ubuntu 16.04 freezes and I have to restart it.

I can't event run `vagrant up --debug`.

I am using [widgetbox-php53](https://github.com/bmckinney/widgetbox-php53) box.

Comment: similar problem here with same version of ubuntu.

Comment: Same here. It freezes at `booting vm`

Comment: I have the exact same issue. When running "vagrant up" on "booting vm" my ubuntu freezes. Problem started ocuring today.

Comment: Might be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/173003. (sorry I can't post comment).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a while updating Vagrant to 2.0.1 and VirtualBox to 5.2, it solved the problem for me.

I was using Vagrant 1.9.4 and VirtualBox 5.0.

Comment: Also fixed it for me. Had to destroy and re-up my boxes though...

Comment: +1, though I found that upgrading my Vagrant didn't help, but upgrading VirtualBox to [5.2.4](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) helped. I also had to run `sudo apt-get remove` on any `virtualbox-` programs and also run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` after upgrading VirtualBox.

Comment: Also, it's important to install with apt by manually adding the repo source instead of downloading the .deb file

Comment: While not really a Vagrant issue (it seems that it is a VirtualBox issue), here is a thread on GitHub discussing this problem and the fix:
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9407

Answer (score 18):

So, I had the same problem freezing at `booting VM` using *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*.

And to solve this in some steps with a lot of hard resets - I've updated to *Vagrant 2.0.1* and *VirtualBox 5.2*.

**Check what versions you have:**

- `vagrant -v` (opened the GUI: Help --> About)
- `virtualbox -v`

**Vagrant**

1. Remove old `index` and `index.lock` files in folder `/home/USER/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/`
2. Download Vagrant 2.0.1 https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
3. install package `sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.0.1_x86_64.deb`

**Virtualbox**

Remove the current virtualbox

1. run `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*` to remove all files
2. Check if anything is left `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`
3. (I had to) remove `sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-virtualbox`

Add repository for Virtualbox (use **apt** to install)

- `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
- Add the line `deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib`
- Add key `wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`
- `sudo apt-get update`

Install latest virtualbox

1. run `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2`
2. run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` to rebuild the settings

**Issues I had**

You probably need to destroy your box and build again.

**Vagrant user issue**

```
The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
be used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
```

Removed the .vagrant folder `rm -rf .vagrant` to solve that.

**Duplicated VM names issue**

```
The name of your virtual machine couldn't be set because VirtualBox
is reporting another VM with that name already exists. Most of the
time, this is because of an error with VirtualBox not cleaning up
properly. To fix this, verify that no VMs with that name do exist
(by opening the VirtualBox GUI). If they don't, then look at the
folder in the error message from VirtualBox below and remove it
if there isn't any information you need in there.
```

I had issues with duplicated Virtualbox names as `VBoxManage: error: Could not rename the directory` error prevented `vagrant up` from finishing. Just removed the folders in my Virtualbox VMs folder and through the GUI.

**Machine index issue**

This is what started my adventure and got me here from Googling.

```
The machine index which stores all required information about
running Vagrant environments has become corrupt. This is usually
caused by external tampering of the Vagrant data folder.

Vagrant cannot manage any Vagrant environments if the index is
corrupt. Please attempt to manually correct it. If you are unable
to manually correct it, then remove the data file at the path below.
This will leave all existing Vagrant environments "orphaned" and
they'll have to be destroyed manually.
```

Comment: This is by far the best and most explanatory answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: These steps worked perfectly for me! I actually didn't even have the issues which were were reported at the end of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to upgrade the Virtualbox and Vagrant version.

Vagrant is easy to update (I updated to 2.0.1)

Here is how I updated the Virtualbox(more or less) to 5.1:

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox-X.X
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-X.X virtualbox-qt virtualbox-dkms
```

Now, install the Virtualbox(it's important to [install with apt](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions))

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
```

Restart and build your VM again

PS: Never build vagrant with `sudo`