# VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I am trying to run Cuckoo sandbox in my Ubuntu 18.04 and got the sandbox VMs working in the headless mode.
I want to see the STDOUT when the program is executing, for that I thought I will enable the GUI mode in virtualbox.
I enabled the GUI mode by editing the mode parameter in virtualbox.conf.

Then I am getting the following error:

```
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine '192.168.56.1011' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I am getting the same error when I try to start the VM using the VBoxManage command standalone (without using Cuckoo).
I saw that this error was posted by many people online, but the suggested solutions did not work (seems like there are many reasons that this error can come).

Standalone VBoxManage command I used:

```
VBoxManage startvm 192.168.56.1011 --type gui
```

System information:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux 4.15.0-210-generic #221-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 18 08:32:52 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ VBoxManage --version
5.2.44r139111
```

What I tried so far:

1. Installing dkms and virtualbox-ext-pack packages and running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`
2. Making sure I have the `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` and it's not empty
3. Suggestions given in [VBoxManage is unable to start vm code NS_ERROR_FAILURE ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995338/vboxmanage-is-unable-to-start-vm-code-ns-error-failure-ubuntu-16-04)

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: All of the error numbers in this question are Microsoft error messages. Nothing to do with Ubuntu. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-may-receive-error-code-0x80004005-or-other-error-codes-when-you-try-to-start-a-windows-xp-based-computer-a15f5b2f-642d-24ac-4912-1570a6bcedec#:~:text=This%20problem%20may%20occur%20if,requires%20is%20damaged%20or%20missing.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: @guiverc This question was on topic when it was asked on April 23, 2023.

Comment: @guiverc Please, are you going to understand some day that you can't retroactively close questions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this error in Ubuntu 22.04  until I found the error behind "NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine".
I tried to start my machine in console using vboxheadless:

```
$ vboxheadless -s "Your VM name"

VBoxHeadless: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VBoxHeadless: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VBoxHeadless: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

Since the reinstall did not previously work I searched for new error and found this post https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=88900

Changing the owner of the folders bellow and fixed my issue. Don't know how but the folders were owned by my linux user instead of root.

```
sudo chown root:root /usr
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/virtualbox
```